# How to add RectIntl Formatted message as html attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have a header logo image for which alt and title attribute should render from i18n messages.

## message_en.json

```
{
    "logoTitle": "Link open in new tab or window",
    "logoAlt": "some description goes here.." 
}
```

## header.js

```
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl/dist';

<a
  href={url}
  title={<FormattedMessage id="logoTitle"/>}
> 
  <img
      src={src}
      alt={<FormattedMessage id='logoAlt' />}
  />
</a>
```

In the browser, alt and title renders as [Object][Object]

```
<a title="[object Object]">
    <img id="masthead__logo__img" src="../assets/images/logo.png" alt="[object Object]">
</a>
```

How do I render FormattedMessage in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormattedMessage` is a React component that renders HTML. To render a plain string, use `intl.formatMessage` function instead:

```
title={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'logoTitle' })}
```

Comment: logoTitle is not a plain string. let me add the message to the question. {
    "logoTitle": "Link open in new tab or window",
    "logoAlt": "some description goes here.." }

Comment: @dragonfly Well, `title` attribute won't accept anything except a string, unfortunately.

Comment: @dragonfly Have you tried my code? :) If you dont have access to `intl`, just inject it to your component with HoC or react intl hook.

Comment: I injected intl with HoC. Its now rendering

Answer (score 0):

#### Potential Solution

Use the `useIntl` hook to render a plain string.

```
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl'; 

const intl = useIntl(); // place this within your function / class.
```

```
<a
  href={url}
  title={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'logoTitle' })} />}
> 
  <img
      src={src}
      alt={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'logoAlt' })} />}
  />
</a>
```

#### Debugging

You can `console.log(intl.formatMessage({ id: 'logoTitle' });` outside of the prop to see what value is being fetched for that identifier.

Comment: Did exactly the same. It renders now. Thanks

Comment: Since this shows how to import `useIntl` and other information, is this not a more accurate answer? Either way, good luck. Please upvote. :)